# PrimeFaces customize theme crashes on java war deployment

Tags: java, jsf, tomcat, primefaces

I deploy the war file in tomcat 7. It looks fine when I open it from this link:
http://193.174.236.128:8080/book-term/. But it crashes when I try to redirect it from another webpage. My project configurations are: JSF framework 2.2, primefaces 5.0. I also put the customize theme jar inside the lib folder and build it with my library jar. And also configured necessary primefaces theme in web.xml.

I added at the server that serves mysite.de.com:

```
<Location /term>
   Order allow,deny
   Allow from all
   ProxyPass http://193.174.236.128:8080/book-term/
</Location>
```

Please help.

Comment: well, its not the same ip address for starters. 236 vs 240 in the third segment

Comment: a theme crashing? Never heard of that... it is all just css... what does it crash? Please try to be more specific

Comment: It runs fine on the server where I installed Tomcat and deploy it. But if I redirected it from a page which is in different server it redirect but crashed. Does not show the data table and it looks without the primefaces theme. Please help me to solve this problem.